# How to teak Particle swarm to have unique values in every particle after velocity update, where some value must be integer and some float

Tags: optimization, integer, particles

I am trying to solve PSO (Particle Swarm Optimisation) to have a particle where some values must be integers and must be unique and some are float (may not be unique)
e.g. a solution like this is desirable after every velocity update:
{0,2,1,5,4,6,8,7,0.087,0.345}
The first eight values must be unique and integers and last two can be regular updates.
The problem I am having is that after velocity update the first eight values tend to duplicate like e.g.: {0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0.76,0.345}. How this can be achieved?
Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the velocity (and position) update for a single particle, I assume you perform some discretisation of the first 6 of the 8 (position?) values to transform them from floating points to integers. In this step, you need to define a measure to ensure the uniqueness of the integer numbers.

Lets say, for some particle i, that we have the following position matrix after the velocity update (leaving out the 7th and 8th entry)

```
posVector(particle i) = {0.1, -0.2, 1.3, 6.2, 2.4, 1.6}.
```

If we just round these number, we would end up with integers

```
posVectorInt(particle i) = {0, 0, 1, 6, 2, 2},
```

in which the entries are non-unique. One simple way to fix this would be to, prior to transforming float->int, ranking the numbers in position 1 through 6, e.g., w.r.t. increasing value, as

```
posVectorRank(particle i) = {2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 4}.
```

Next, we could start rounding particles, starting with rank 1, but, from rank 2 and onwards, ascertaining that the rounded value is not equal to the previously rounded value. In some pseudo/mixed-code,

```
// Rank 1 rounding
for entry in posVectorRank where posVectorRank(entry) = 1 
    posVector(entry) = round(posVector(entry)) 

// Rank 2->6 rounding
for entry in posVectorRank where posVectorRank(entry) = 2 to 6
    previousInteger = posVector(entry-1)
    if round(posVector(entry-1)) equals previousInteger
        posVector(entry) = round(posVector(entry))+1
    else
        posVector(entry) = round(posVector(entry))
```

This would result in the final posVectorInt as

```
posVectorInt(particle i) = {1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 3}.
```

Note, however, that it's probably better to build a more sophisticated "rank -> integer" function that takes into account e.g. swarm best or particle best values w.r.t. the objective function.

If you're using this method to find the optimal solution to some optimization problem with mixed continuous and integer valued (decision) variables, note that such problems are non-convex. Going, by rounding, from a "good" continuously relaxed variable vector to one that is (integer) feasible in the non-relaxed problem doesn't necessarily yield a "good" solution in the latter. Hence, if you decide to use PSO in such context, the "rank -> integer" method should probably contain some clever heuristics, constructed with the actual problem to be solved in mind. This, in itself, is---in my experience---an unusual approach for using PSO, as PSO can generally be considered a "brute-force" method of solving nonlinear/nonconvex optimisation problems with *continuous* variables.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the detailed answer. The order of integer number also matters. So i think ranking them is not a good solution. I wonder if you can give opinion on this, that if the dupliactes are removed and replaced by the numbers from the array of availabe integers, would this be a good solution?

Comment: e.g avaialbe={0,1,2,3,4,5} and particle[i]=[0,1,1,2,3,4} ...after removing duplicates partcile[i]=[0,1,5,2,3,4}

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the specific application of your PSO problem, but note that the simple rounding method I described above will somewhat keep the order of the integers (depending on separation between them), but this should only be seen as a "skeleton" that you can work further on yourself. As I've written, "... it's probably better to build a more sophisticated "rank -> integer" function ...". However, will add to my answer what the resulting posVectorInt array is, for the simple answer given.

Comment: With regard to your proposal; again this depends on the specific problem you're trying to solve. Your approach will insert an additional random segment into your PSO (as 2nd, 3rd etc instance duplicate numbers will be randomized in your range), but perhaps this is intended. Difficult to answer any more thoroughly given the information you've stated. If you satisfied with the answer, please mark your question as answered, or edit your question to contain more specifics, possibly allowing for a more specific answer.